# Does jquery-migrate find all "errors" at load or at runtime?

Tags: jquery, jquery-migrate

If I'm to upgrade jquery, and I use jquery-migrate to give me warnings on depreciated code, do I need to exercise all functions on the page to catch all things to upgrade, or is it enough to load each page and see if the console log shows errors?

I guess and hope the latter, as no script is generated on the fly or other exotic ideas to make the javascript change after loading.

Comment: Darn. I search for this, 9 months later, and I find this. Nothing new appeared.

Answer (score 2):

The jquery-migrate plugins triggers a warning whenever a deprecated function is called. As such, it's necessary to test all functions on the page: simply loading the page won't show all the errors.

I whipped up a simple example that shows this:

```js
// should be $('#test').on('click', ...
$('#test').click(function() {
    $('#test2').focus(); // should be $('#test').trigger('focus')
})

$('#test2').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).val('from js');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/3.1.0/jquery-migrate.js"></script>

<button id="test">Initial</button>
<input id="test2" />
```

- If you run the snippet, you'll see an error when the page loads, warning that you can't use the `click` shorthand (you need to use `.on()`).
- If you then click on the button, you'll see a new warning, saying that you can't use the `focus` shorthand (you need to user `.trigger()`).

As you can see, the second error doesn't show up when the page loads, so you need to test all your functions.

Comment: Darn... I wish there were a static analysis I could run on all pages.

Comment: so do I ...so do I.